# What happens when an open string start to stretch in a full Neumann boundary scenario?

Tags: special-relativity, string-theory

I'm only reading about string theory. I'm an undergraduate. I see that for a full Neumann boundary condition the ends of a relativist string travel at the speed of light. If they travel in opposite directions the string could start to stretch?

Comment: 1. Why is this tagged [tag:topological-field-theory]? 2. Explain your notation! What is $\phi$, what is an "infinite expectation value" supposed to mean, is $g_s$ the string coupling constant or something else? 3. The string length is *fixed* to be $\ell = 2\pi \sqrt{\alpha'}$ where $\alpha' = (2\pi T)^{-1}$ is the Regge slope with $T$ the tension appearing as the prefactor in the Nambu-Goto action. Why do you think the string can "stretch"? The tension/length is a *parameter in the action*, not something that can change dynamically.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I fixed some ot the notations. The tension $T$ in front of the action is fixed. Classicaly if the end points of the string travel in oposite directions in a way to stretch the string what happens? (they travel at the speed of light). If the string can't split some point would won and brings the other back. But in quantum mechanics may be the act of stretch could create a high concentration of energy in the middel of the string.

Comment: Analogously with the crude picture of string made by gluons. The act of stretch them can produce a quark-antiquark pair in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string does not stretch. The Neumann boundary condition is
$$ \partial_\sigma \vec{X} =  0$$
where $\sigma$ is the spatial world-sheet coordinate, i.e. the derivative in the spatial direction of the string.  It vanishing means *precisely* that the string does not stretch since stretching means a change in the $\sigma$-direction. The endpoints move transversely to the string.

Comment: If the initial state is such that $\partial_\tau|_{0} X^{i} > 0$ and $\partial_\tau|_{\pi} X^{i} < 0$, when $i$ is some direction on space. Increase the length of the string as evollution on time is what I mean by stretch.

Comment: @Nogueira: I have no idea what you're on about. The length of a (classical) string can obviously only change when it is *taut*, i.e. a straight line. Otherwise it just floats around. Now, if the string is a straight line, stretching (or shrinking, for that matter) means $\partial_\sigma X \neq 0$, which is *precisely forbidden* by the Neumann boundary conditions (and also by the Dirichlet one, trivially, since the endpoints can't move). Strings don't stretch.

Comment: Thnak you. I understand now.